# How to select a text and put it directly on the search and replace bar of IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm an **IntelliJ** user since years and I work on a Mac.
For a long I was able to execute like an automata the following procedure:

1. select a portion of a text in a file using the mouse
2. pressing a combination of keys
3. seeing the selected text in the find & replace bar of the IDE.

Now, *I can't remember how to do it*.
I have search through [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-a-file.html) of the search & replace in a file, but I cannot see that option.

Just to avoid confusion, the toolbar I'm talking about is the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ on linux (Keymap : Default for xwin) and to select text I use Ctrl+W or Mouse double click. Then ctrl+R will put this text in replace text box

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a kind of bug. It should work by selecting the text and pressing `cmd+r`. 
Cases when it works:

- I select a piece of text in a line and I press `cmd+R`.
- I select the whole line (including white spaces/tabs at the beginning)

Case when does not work:

- I select a line from the first character to the last.

More context. I use **IntelliJ 2017.2.5** on *Mac Os Sierra*.